# Master-detail: submit a child record with no master ID, let BeforeInsert trigger populate it?

Tags: trigger, master-detail

I have a child object in a master-detail relationship.  If I insert a child record with no parent ID value, but I write a BeforeInsert trigger to populate the parent ID, will Salesforce allow the record to proceed, or does the system reject the record before it reaches the trigger?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That should work fine.  Looking at the [trigger execution order](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_triggers_order_of_execution.htm), the "**before**" triggers execute before any system validation (unless it comes from a standard UI page, which in this case, is impossible as you can't create a record without a parent).